# Magento $collection->join - Multiple

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I'm currently extending the Magento Invoice Grid to display some additional columns.
I've got the data that I need for most, but I'm struggling to get more than 1 Column from the same Database Table.

This is what I have in my `_prepareCollection`

```
$collection->join('invoice','main_table.entity_id=invoice.entity_id','subtotal');
$collection->join('invoice','main_table.entity_id=invoice.entity_id','discount_description');
```

I assume I need to drop the second line and put them into somekind of array, I'm just not sure on how to do that as I don't work with PHP too much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, this was much more simple than I was expecting, I managed to work it out with the following:

```
    $collection->join('invoice', 'main_table.entity_id = invoice.entity_id', array(
        'subtotal',
        'discount_description'
    ));
```

Comment: This is simple, it's about joining with single table multi times. How about joining multiple tables ?